# How to change date time MDS format?

Tags: ssis

We are working with Microsof SSIS ,when we are loading the  data in MDS ( master data services ) ,  we are facing the following issue

The date is concatenated with the time.

**Example [1]:**

```
      Date      Time
YY : MM : DD : 00 : 00 :00
```

What we want is the following format (the date without the time part)

```
   Date      
YY : MM : DD
```

We have used the date mask but it not working as expected .

How to resolve this issue ?

Comment: What is the data source type?

Comment: date time  what we want is to convert date time to date

Comment: I mean the the data source: i.e. Sql Server, Text file, excel, etc...

Comment: the data source is sql server

Comment: Since the datasource is SQL Server, why not do a `datetime` to `date` conversion in SQL? `NewDate = cast(datetime as date)` or something similar.  It would be easier than doing it in SSIS.